# D3js Chord Diagram Multiple Groups

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to replicate the "super group" functionality like in an example I found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/farazshuja/raw/6225ffc34c23ade0de169c4d96252bbe/). Even though my start and end angles are correct according to my main matrix, they Arc is not aligning correctly. I have a feeling it is the InnerRadius and OuterRadius on Arc2 but I can't narrow down what needs to change. My example code can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p1c77b62/2/). You can see the brown arc does not align to the start angle of Index 0 or endAngle of Index 2.

```
//define grouping with colors
    var groups = [
    {sIndex: 0, eIndex: 2, title: 'SuperCategory 1', color: '#c69c6d'}

  ];
  var cD = chord(matrix).groups;

   console.log(cD);


  //draw arcs
  for(var i=0;i<groups.length;i++) {
    var __g = groups[i];  
    console.log(cD[__g.sIndex].startAngle);
    var arc1 = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius)
      .startAngle(cD[__g.sIndex].startAngle) 
      .endAngle(cD[__g.eIndex].endAngle) 

    svg.append("path").attr("d", arc1).attr('fill', __g.color).attr('id', 'SuperCategory' + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my path for my original groups (Test1, Test2, etc) had a translation applied to them. I had to apply the same translation to the SuperCategory ptah and then add to Inner/Outer radius in order to move it as an outer arc. I have updated the [jsfiddle to reflect the change](https://jsfiddle.net/u0n8Lq8p/2/).

```
 // Add to Radii to move arc flush against inner arc
      .innerRadius(innerRadius + 20)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius + 20)
      .startAngle(cD[__g.sIndex].startAngle) 
      .endAngle(cD[__g.eIndex].endAngle) 

// add the translation
    svg.append("path").attr("d", arc1).attr('fill', __g.color).attr('id', 'SuperCategory' + i).attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```